# 405 Method not Allowed on uploading a shapefile via REST API on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, apache, request

I'm using PHP cURL to upload a Shapefile to GeoServer. It works fine in a development server. But when I deploy to Stage server and I try the same I get:

> 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_workspace/datastores/my_datastore/file.shp.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at my.stage-domain.com Port 80

I've tried Google about how to enable PUT requests, but nothing seems to work. I've installed both development and stage servers (both running Ubuntu 16.04) and I didn't had to enable PUT on my development server. It just worked.

Looking around here I've found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169724/openlayers-error-405-method-not-allowed-while-attempting-to-add-a-wfs-t-layer) and the answers suggests to register the webapp, but I don't even know how to do that...

Do you have any suggestions? I'm really stuck here...

**UPDATE:**

As suggested in comments, I replaced the *Linux binary* version for the `geoserver.war` file running over **Tomcat 8**. I've also reinstalled the server so now I have **Ubuntu 17.04** and **Apache 2.4.27** as in my development server. Unfortunately, the issue remains exactly the same. So I guess it's a web server issue.

My `access.log` file on Apache2 logs shows:

> aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd - - [08/Jan/2018:15:02:27 +0000] "PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_workspace/datastores/my_datastore/file.shp HTTP/1.1" 405 629 "1" "-"

**UPDATE 2:**

Some answers and comments suggest to use `POST` instead of `PUT` method. I am uploading a zipped shapefile to an existing datastore. This:

> `/workspaces/{workspaceName}/datastores/{storeName}/{method}.{format}`
>
> Uploads files to the data store, creating it if necessary

In the [API docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/datastores.yaml) it says clearly that I must use `PUT`

[image: Invalid POST]

[image: Use PUT]

Comment: are you using the correct username/password? check the geoserver log file and see if you get to GS, it looks as if this might be an apache error message.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my config files with the correct user/pass for stage server... I'll try to check GS' logs

Comment: You're right Ian, there's no record of any PUT request on GS' log... In fact I already tried to "allow PUT" in my apache2 config without any success. I did the ["Linux binary"](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/linux.html) install... Maybe I should try ["Web Archive"](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/war.html) because that's what I did on my development server, and it worked from the beginning....

Comment: I would always use the war in tomcat in production

Comment: I'll do that hopping that it works. I'll update/delete my question afterwards... Thanks!

Comment: if you go directly to localhost:8080/geoserver/rest - does that work?

Comment: Yes, it works. The first time it asks for Authentication and if I log in with my geoserver's admin user I'm able to list the endpoints.

Comment: so either your web server is not forwarding the requests or the authentication - either way you should probably go to serverfault or stackoverflow

Comment: This sounds like a CORS issue https://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/

Comment: Maybe you should try POST rather than PUT?

Comment: Hi @JordiNebot. I see what you're saying. I'll run some tests locally and get back to you here soon.

Answer (score 4):

Try running it without the apache proxy first, that will rule out it being in the web server. You should be able to point to localhost:8000 in order to get to GeoServer directly.

The 405 error is unusual for GeoServer.

EDIT: Looking at the documentation, [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_examples.html), it seems that you should be using POST rather than PUT. Can you try that?

EDIT2: The documentation seems to be misleading, as, from testing, I can use PUT and not POST with the kind of URL you're using. But regardless, I've tested and this code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

shapefile = "/Users/alex/Desktop/example_shapefile.zip"
url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/test_workspace/datastores/test_datastore/file.shp'

headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/zip"
}

with open(shapefile, 'rb') as data:
    r = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=('admin', 'geoserver'), headers=headers)

print(r.status_code, r.text)
```

I'm not sure what you're doing in PHP, but I certainly didn't get a 405 error when using PUT, though I did with a POST.

Note that I did get an error about 'magic numbers' if I didn't set the headers with the Content-type.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the latest GeoServer then PUT is not for creating a new datastore. Use POST instead as documented in

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/datastores.yaml

[image]